# Route Split for OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, routing

I'm attempting to install a static route for a Mac Pro desktop.  I'm using Route Split 1.4, which creates a startup script called /etc/routes.sh (the script waits for the interface to come online before applying its changes).

However, after I reboot, I lose the static route I entered.  Here's what I get in the /var/log/system.log:

```
-Mac-Pro syslog[70]: routes.sh: Starting RouteSplit
-Mac-Pro /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow[51]: Login Window Application Started
-Mac-Pro syslog[75]: routes.sh: static route xxx.xx.x.x/xx xxx.xx.x.x
-Mac-Pro net.routes.static[66]: route: writing to routing socket: Network is unreachable
-Mac-Pro net.routes.static[66]: add net xxx.xx.x.x: gateway xxx.xx.x.x: Network is unreachable
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the `routes.sh` file, I added `sleep 10` just after the line that starts routesplit.  It looks like:

```
syslog -s -l 1 routes.sh: Starting RouteSplit

sleep 10
```